# Memory leaked when DLL unloaded

Tags: dll, memory-leaks, com, openssl

I have the following inside a Windows DLL (C++, pseudocode):

```
void func()
{
    static void *ptr;

     if ( !ptr )
         ptr = malloc(50000000);
}
```

The problem is that if the DLL is repeatedly loaded and unloaded (via `LoadLibrary` / `FreeLibrary`) then the values of static data do not persist; and so each load/free cycle leaks all that memory.

Is there any solution to the memory leak, subject to the requirements that `func` cannot be changed?

---

Background: In the "real code", `func` is actually initializing OpenSSL. The OpenSSL initialization mallocs some tables and retains a static pointer to those tables; and there is no function for deallocating that memory.

I actually submitted a patch a few years ago to 0.9.8-something that did provide deallocation functions corresponding to all such allocation functions that I knew about; but checking a 1.0.0 release, someone has commented out much of it saying "this should never be deallocated!!!".  The people in charge apparently didn't know about unloading DLLs, and they assumed that the static pointer retained its value for the lifetime of the process.

Also, in the "real code" the DLL contains COM objects but that makes no difference that I am aware of. I am currently working around the problem by having `DllCanUnloadNow` always return No , but that is not ideal.

Comment: Your situation sounds like exactly what `DllCanUnloadNow` is designed for. Why is it not ideal?

Comment: note: [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533033/memory-leaks-on-dll-unload?rq=1) is similar, however it focuses on what the application doing the Load/Free can do about the leak; rather than on what the DLL can do.

Comment: @GregHewgill Perhaps I misunderstand the purpose of unloading a DLL; I thought the point of it was to allow the calling process to reclaim memory used by the DLL once the DLL is no longer needed.  My DLL does use a lot of memory besides this particular leaked chunk, so I thought it would be "good behaviour" to permit my DLL to be unloaded.

Comment: In most cases, yes, but in your case since you can't clean up all the allocations performed by your DLL, I would clean up what you can and leave the OpenSSL stuff around.

Comment: Woould it be possible to maintain a "load count" and only initialize/deinitialize OpenSSL once?

Comment: @sharptooth Once Unloaded, all static variables are reset (so OpenSSL would need reinitialization again on the next Load).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: So does it use the same runtime and heap as all the other libraries? Would it be possible to recompile is so that it uses a separate runtime and a separate heap which would effectively be recycled on unload?

Comment: @sharptooth interesting idea, it might be possible to use a separate heap or at least wrap all of its allocations. I will investigate

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I actually meant compiling OpenSSL against a "static runtime" which would automatically get it a separate runtime heap. The problem is that whatever is allocated on that heap cannot be freed to any other heap.

Comment: If `ptr` can somehow be made accessible outside of func(), then the uninitializing can me done in `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

Comment: "they assumed that the static pointer retained its value for the lifetime of the process" - I think they assume shared objects and DLLs don't get loaded/unloaded. They also think its OK to leak on unload because the memory is cleaned up when the process exits. (I've had this discussion with them on the mailing list).

Comment: @jww Are they unaware of the fact that DLLs can be unloaded and reloaded (and actually that this is very common, and that hundreds of reload cycles can occur over the lifetime of a process)? I feel that it is a case of "Lol Windows.. get a real OS" on their part.