# FreeLibrary leak on VC14 but not on VC9

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, memory-leaks

I am using a third party library which apparently has a memory leak that we first discovered when upgrading from Visual Studio 2008 (VC9.0) to Visual Studio 2015 (VC14.0). On Windows I load the library at run-time using LoadLibrary and when done using it I unload it using FreeLibrary. When compiling and linking with VC9.0 all memory allocated by the library gets freed on FreeLibrary while using VC14.0 some memory is never freed. The memory profile for my test program below can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awp3b.jpg.

Why is the behavior different for VC9.0 and VC14.0? And can one do anything to avoid the leak without changing the source of the library, like mimic the behavior of VC9.0?

The only thing I could find here on SO is this: [Memory leaks on DLL unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533033/memory-leaks-on-dll-unload) which hasn't really helped me, though one answer hints at some hacky solution.

---

I have made a minimal working example to show that it is not specific to the library. First I create a small library in C with a function that allocates some memory and never deallocates it:

leaklib.h:

```
#ifndef LEAKLIB_H_
#define LEAKLIB_H_

__declspec( dllexport ) void leak_memory(int memory_size);

#endif
```

leaklib.c:

```
#include "leaklib.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void leak_memory(int memory_size)
{
    double * buffer;
    buffer = (double *) malloc(memory_size);
    if (buffer != NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocated %d bytes of memory\n", memory_size);
    }
}
```

And then a program that loads the library, calls the memory leak function, and then unloads the library again - repeatedly so that we can track the memory over time.

memleak.c:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    HINSTANCE handle;
    int load_success;
    void (*leak_memory)(int);
    int dll_unloaded;

    Sleep(30000);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        handle = LoadLibrary(TEXT("leaklib.dll"));

        leak_memory = GetProcAddress(handle, "leak_memory");

        printf("%d: leaking memory...\n", i);
        leak_memory(50*1024*1024);
        printf("ok\n\n");

        Sleep(3000);

        dll_unloaded = FreeLibrary(handle);
        if (!dll_unloaded)
        {
            printf("Could not free dll'");
            return 1;
        }

        Sleep(3000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I then build the library with:

```
cl.exe /MTd /LD leaklib.c
```

and the program with

```
cl.exe memleak.c
```

with cl.exe from either VS9.0 or VS14.0.

Comment: CRT versions before the one used in VS2012 had a knack for hiding memory leak bugs, they created their own heap with HeapCreate().  But no more, allocations are now made from the default process heap, the one returned by GetProcessHeap().

Comment: but you not free memory allocated by `leak_memory` - so leak and must be here

Comment: As you were able to reproduce without the library: why do you suspect it is in that library? And why did you double-tag as two different languages? If that is C, don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends. Remove the unrelated tag.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that VC9 inadvertently deallocated memory that a reasonable program might expect to still be there - after all, `free()` wasn't called. Of course, this is one of those areas where the CRT can't please everybody - you wanted the automagic `free` behavior.

Underlying this is the fact that `FreeLibrary` is a pretty simple Win32 function. It removes a chunk of code from your address space. You might get a few final calls to `DllMain`, but as `DllMain`'s documentation notes: you can't do much there. One thing that's especially hard is figuring out what memory would need to be freed, other than DLL's code and data segment.

Comment: Are you sure it was deallocated with VC9 and not just "nicely hidden" in a secondary heap?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I'm not sure it even was consistent or reliable.

Comment: It seems like this is the same thing Hans Passant speaks about above. They simply may have changed the behavior of FreeLibrary. Impossible to find any information on this on anywhere - Microsofts website isn't any help. Anyone more lucky than I?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I'm pretty sure it was in fact deallocated before because we have been running this software through CI for years with tests loading/unloading the library 100s of times without problem. After the change to VC14 the tests started crashing due to insufficient memory.